# gsub function in R doesn't replace

Tags: r

Please anyone tell me what the problem is here? I have data where between digits there is whitespace. For example, instead `1234.00`, I have `1 234.00`. I must replace that `" " with ""`, using the `gsub` function in R.

I wrote this function:

```
data(mydata)

fixup.num <- function(x) 
    as.numeric(gsub(pattern = " ", replacement = "", x, fixed = TRUE))

fixup.num(mydata$safety)
```

But after it's done, I can see that the spaces weren't replaced and `mydata` has not changed. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: please show all you code and provide a minimal set of the input data that reproduces the problem.

Comment: It seems you didn't re-assign anything. Try `mydata$safety <- fixup.num(mydata$safety)` and then look at your data

Comment: thank you my dear friends. Yes, i forgot re-assign. But after transformations i got strange values. For example in variable X , before transformation: the min value=0
the max value =800
after i replaced spaces,  i got  strange values:
the min value=0
the max value =3404
what's happened why replacing so influenced on value. I can't upload my dataset, because it's size 200mb in csv format. Maybe you can help me understand how appear new values. Thank you.

Comment: Noone can tell for sure what happend with your data without  actually knowing it. But I would assume that you don't know what the actual max value was before replacing, because you could not correctly convert to numeric. Since, e. g., `as.numeric("1 234.1")` results in `NA`, no value above 1000 could be correctly converted. I am only surprised that the max value was not closer to 1000.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nifty function `destring` in the `taRifx` package that does exactly what you want. I use it when I have a vector of numberics that are misformatted as strings.

```
library(taRifx)
x <- c("1 234", "3 456", "9 876")
destring(x)
# [1] 1234 3456 9876
```

This function also cleans up other kinds of problematic numerics.

```
x <- c("1,234", "$84.27", "3 Help I'm stuck in a numeric factory 27")
destring(x)
```

If you look at the function definition you see that it's powered by a call to `gsub`.

```
function (x, keep = "0-9.-") 
{
    return(as.numeric(gsub(paste("[^", keep, "]+", sep = ""), 
        "", x)))
}
```

If you don't want to have to load the library you can just use a slightly modified version of the `gsub` call directly. Just replace `x` with the data you want cleaned.

```
as.numeric(gsub(paste("[^", "0-9.-", "]+", sep = ""), "", x))
```