# Problem with type conversion from character to decimal numbers in R (data from web scraping)

Tags: r, web-scraping, type-conversion

I've preformed web scraping and get a dataframe with few character vectors which I want to convert to decimal number vectors.

```
dataframe <- "https://aplikacje.nfz.gov.pl/umowy/AgreementsPlan/GetPlans?ROK=2019&ProviderId=25166&OW=01&OrthopedicSupply=False&Code=3401036&AgreementTechnicalCode=1892709" %>% read_html() %>% html_node("table") %>% html_table()
dataframe[,5] <- as.numeric(dataframe[,5]) # that doesn't work
```

For example I want to convert this column:

```
head(dataframe[,5])
[1] "147 839 030,03" "147 839 030,03" "147 839 030,03" "147 839 030,03" "147 839 030,03" "147 839 030,03"
```

into decimal column to be able to analyze this data.
I want the elements of that vector look like, for example: 147839030.03 (so a numeric-type value with two numbers after dot).
It's strange to me because functions like "as.numeric", "type.convert" don't work.
I also tried to do this by first replacing white spaces " " with "" and "," with "." by applying gsub() and other appropriate functions but without results...

Comment: Your code is giving errors `Error: Please supply one of css or xpath`  Can you please update.  Also, please update with what you need as expected output i.e. `"147 839 030,03" "147 839 030,03"`

Comment: The problem might be that your numbers use a comma (`,`) for a decimal point instead of the dot (`.`) which is more common (especially in US and commonwealth countries).

Comment: If that's the case, you can either replace the commas with dots & then convert or use some function that can parse the commas.

Comment: @akrun Ok, now it should be possible to scrap this table from WWW.

Comment: @adamB. After replacing comma with dot the problem remains

Comment: Can you please check the solution posted below.  The values in the `head(dataframe[,5])` is different from what you showed

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can replace the space (`\\s+`) with blank, then replace the `,` with `.` and convert to `numeric` with `as.numeric`

```
out <- as.numeric(sub(",", ".", gsub("\\s+", "", dataframe[,5])))
str(out)
#num [1:158] 4967679 1062094 4122 123136 0 ...
head(out, 5)
#[1] 4967679 1062094    4122  123136       0
```

Comment: After applying your code I get: "Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion". But it seems like you've got correct results and I doing the same get Warning massage

Comment: @Marcelina  Can you show your output?  I am only using the same code to generate the 'dataframe'.  May be you can check yoour locale settings

Comment: `head(out) [1] NA NA NA NA  0 NA`

Comment: @Marcelina I can't reproduce it.  can you check the output of `gsub("\\s+", "", dataframe[,5])` and `sub(",", ".", gsub("\\s+", "", dataframe[,5]))`

Comment: `> out <- gsub("\\s+", "", dataframe[,5])
> head(out)
[1] "4 967 679,00" "1 062 094,00" "4 122,00"     "123 136,00"   "0,00"         "24 801,00"` So replacing spaces doesn't work for me

Comment: `> out <- sub(",", ".", gsub("\\s+", "", dataframe[,5]))
> head(out)
[1] "4 967 679.00" "1 062 094.00" "4 122.00"     "123 136.00"   "0.00"         "24 801.00" ` SO only replacing "," for "." works

Comment: @Marcelina Not sure why `gsub` is behaving like that because `\\s+` implies one or more spaces.  Can you try `gsub(" +", "", dataframe[,5])`

Comment: The same. `> out <- gsub(" +", "", dataframe[,5])
> head(out)
[1] "4 967 679,00" "1 062 094,00" "4 122,00"     "123 136,00"   "0,00"         "24 801,00" `

Comment: @Marcelina Can you try `gsub(" +", "", dataframe[,5], perl = TRUE)` Not clear why it is behaving differently.  I am using `R 3.6.2` on a mac

Comment: @Marcelina Can you share the `dput(head(dataframe[,5]))`

Comment: I work on: `> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu and R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)`

Comment: `> out<- dput(head(dataframe[,5]))
c("4 967 679,00", "1 062 094,00", "4 122,00", "123 136,00", 
"0,00", "24 801,00")`

Comment: @Marcelina I can't reproduce the issue `gsub("\\s+", "", c("4 967 679,00", "1 062 094,00", "4 122,00", "123 136,00", "0,00", "24 801,00"))#
[1] "4967679,00" "1062094,00" "4122,00"    "123136,00"  "0,00"       "24801,00"`

Comment: @Marcelina Or with the full code `as.numeric(sub(",", ".",gsub("\\s+", "", c("4 967 679,00", "1 062 094,00", "4 122,00", "123 136,00", "0,00", "24 801,00"))))#
[1] 4967679 1062094    4122  123136       0   24801`

Comment: I found the answer I'll put in below.

Comment: @Marcelina What is the answer

Comment: @arkun Please see below

Answer (score 1):

I found that `taRifx` library works for me. You can also see: ([gsub function in R doesn't replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32651247/gsub-function-in-r-doesnt-replace))

```
> dataframe <- "https://aplikacje.nfz.gov.pl/umowy/AgreementsPlan/GetPlans?ROK=2019&ProviderId=25166&OW=01&OrthopedicSupply=False&Code=3401036&AgreementTechnicalCode=1892709" %>% read_html() %>% html_node("table") %>% html_table()
> library(taRifx)
> out <- gsub(",", ".", dataframe[,5])
> head(out)
[1] "4 967 679.00" "1 062 094.00" "4 122.00"     "123 136.00"   "0.00"         "24 801.00"   
> out1 <- destring(out)
> head(out1)
[1] 4967679 1062094    4122  123136       0   24801
> typeof(out1)
[1] "double"
```

Comment: @akrun thank you for your help. The answer above works for me. As you mentioned, it might be a locale settings issue that determies what works for you and what for me.

Comment: Good to know that at least one method is working for you.  Have a great day!

Comment: @arkun Thank you! In place where I live is 1 am so it's time to go sleep instead of enjoy the day ;))) Greetings!